# Learning C Pointers - Assignment is to print out addresses and the size of variables of three different arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote the following code which works, and I can see that a pointer only takes up (*I think*) 4 bytes of memory; while a plain old array takes up 20 bytes. However, I am not sure entirely why it works!

When I declare my character array I had to make it a pointer, otherwise it would not compile and run.  I then was able to make my character an int type pointer; but I am not sure why this works.

Why can I do this "int *ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;" and not do this "char *ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;" ?

Here's my code:

```
int main(void)
{
int i;

int arrayOfNums[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
char *arrayOfChars[] = {"hello","how","are","you","doing"};
float arrayOfFloats[] = {1.23,2.34,3.45,4.56,5.67};

int *ptrOfNums = arrayOfNums;
int *ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;
float *ptrOfFloats = arrayOfFloats;

printf("\n\n");

printf("----- Array of Numbers -----\n");
printf("The size of this array is %d\n\n", sizeof(arrayOfNums));

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     printf("Value in the array is %d\n", *ptrOfNums);
     printf("Address of pointer is %x\n", ptrOfNums++);
}

printf("\n\n");

printf("----- Array of Characters -----\n");
printf("The size of this array is %d\n\n", sizeof(*arrayOfChars));

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     printf("Value in the array is %s\n", *ptrOfChars);
     printf("Address of pointer is %x\n", ptrOfChars++);
}

printf("\n\n");

printf("----- Mardi Gras -----\n");
printf("The size of this array is %d\n\n", sizeof(arrayOfFloats));

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     printf("Value in the array is %f\n", *ptrOfFloats);
     printf("Address of pointer is %x\n", ptrOfFloats++);
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your assistance!!

Comment: So what is your question? Please work that out clearly and edit your text accordingly.

Comment: Too much code, not enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//This is an array of strings.
char *arrayOfChars[]={"hello","how","are","you","doing"}; 

//This is an array of characters.
char arrayOfChars[]={'h','e','l','l','o',};
```

Each pointer in your array `char *arrayOfChars[]` , points to the first character of each word.
This is all the information you need to find a word from your array.
For example to get the first word of your array you need a pointer to the first character of the string 'hello'. 
Then you will find the next character and the next and so on.
h --> e --> l --> l --> o --> EndOfString.

Answer (score 0):

You declares a array of pointer which is of (char *) type.

```
char *arrayOfChars[] = {"hello","how","are","you","doing"};
```

which means you have:

```
arrayOfChars[0] -> "hello"
arrayOfChars[1] -> "how"
arrayOfChars[2] -> "are"
arrayOfChars[3] -> "you"
arrayOfChars[4] -> "doing"
```

And the sizeof(arrayOfChars[0]) is 4 (4 bytes, this is the size of char * variable), the strlen(arrayOfChars[0]) is 5 (the length of the string "hello"). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is because when you will print the value of arrayOfChars it is an integer(an address of arrayOfChars[0] i.e"Hello").
and your ptrOfChars is pointing to this integer.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayOfChars` is not a array of characters but an array of pointers to strings.  Therefore, the correct definition for `ptrOfChars` should be:

```
char **ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;
```

Assigning `arrayOfChars` to `int *ptrOfChars` works because in this case, the size of a pointer and of an int are both 4 bytes and therefore are identical in size. Furthermore, because C doesn't really do any strong type checking, passing the value of int as the value of a char pointer still works correctly.  However, under a different memory model such as 64 bit, the size of both the pointer and of an int could be different and therefore your code wouldn't work with `int *ptrOfChars`.

To print the size of the array `arrayOfChars`, you need to use `sizeof(arrayOfChars)` instead of `sizeof(*arrayOfChars)`.

Finally, the type for the values for 1.23, 2.34, etc. is `double` and not `float`. To have `float`, you should add a little f at the end: 1.23f, 2.34f, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I do this "int *ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;" and not do this "char *ptrOfChars = arrayOfChars;" ?

Because the type of the *expression* `arrayOfChars` "decays" to type `char **`, not `char *`.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So, given the declaration:

```
char *arrayOfChars[] = {"hello","how","are","you","doing"};
```

the *expression* `arrayOfChars` has type "5-element array of `char *`" (each of the string literals is also an array expression, and also subject to the conversion rule mentioned above).  If `arrayOfChars` appears in an expression where it is *not* the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `*` operators, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char *`", or `char **`.

I would have expected the compiler to complain about initializing an `int *` with a `char **` expression.

Finally, use the `%p` conversion specifier to print out pointer values:

```
printf( "address of arrayOfChars = %p\n", (void *) arrayOfChars );
```

This is one of the few places where an explicit cast to `void *` is needed.